# Should my structured data type be Product or ItemPage?

Tags: google-search, schema.org

I am building structured data sets for my artist studio. We sell lighting / vessels, but not from these web pages (from the store page only).

These pages are about specific products, but with no e-commerce attached.

Should I be listing them as "type": "ItemPage" and use keywords then? I noticed "Product" doesn't offer keywords.

Thank you.

Comment: On [webmasters.se]: [Correct Schema.org type for B2B product (not e-commerce)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/117707/17633)

Comment: Why did you add the [tag:google-search] tag? Does it imply that you want a specific rich result in Google Search? If yes, which one?

Comment: @unor I'm pretty new to this. I know "Product" types can display rich snippets with pricing, but our pages don't have pricing on them. It would be ideal if someone searched for our product and saw the rich snipped product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ItemPage and Product are at different levels. The first provides information about the WebPage (its a sub class of WebPage), and the second is about the entity (item) that is on the WebPage.

So I would say you could define both with Product being the mainEntityOfPage for ItemPage.

You probably want to stick with one official page that defines the product. Or at least, use the same id for every time you mark it up. So if the product is also marked up on the ecommerce site, you probably want to use the id for that entity so that it is clear that you are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Which field is the ID? We do have product pages and e-commerce product pages and I would like to follow your advice here.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Structured Data General Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)** of Google requires to ensure that the structured data represents the main content of the web page to which they refer.

In its turn the **[guide of Google for Product](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product)** informs us:

> Use markup for a specific product, not a category or list of products.

and

> a product page that describes a single product.

Thus, if you are creating structured data for a web page that has a main content sush as description of the product, then in this case you can use the markup for the type **Product**.

If your web page has a list of products or categories, then it may be useful to use markup for type **ItemList** as **[Google suggests](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings#datatypes)**.

Creating markup for the type **Product** has no connection with e-commerce. This can be used to mark up the products of a physical store website.

Comment: I thought with type **Product** google might show rich snippet of the item?